# Conditionally compiling for a minimum version of .NET

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

.NET Standard's promise is that anything written for one version will work for future versions.

Right now I can conditionally compile things e.g.

```
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
// do things
#elif NETSTANDARD1_4 || NETSTANDARD2_0 || NET45
// do other things
#endif
```

But to me this seems poorly scalable, because if I decide to add a new target in the future, e.g. for .NET Standard 2.1, I'll have to go and update it everywhere I have these conditionals.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
#if NETSTANDARD1_3
// do things
#elif NETSTANDARD1_4_OR_GREATER || NET45_OR_GREATER
// do other things
#endif
```

My current solution is to create these `_OR_GREATER` defines manually in my project file. This at least keeps my maintenance down to a single file rather than every source file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
    <DefineConstants>NETSTANDARD1_4_OR_GREATER;$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But, I'm curious if this is already accounted for in some other more standard way. Is this a thing?

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, mind explaining why?

Comment: I do think the question is valid but might need some rephrasing, stating the intent - a DefineConstant for minimum versions.

Comment: (oh and it wasn't me, I upvoted because I find this very useful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with a few msbuild tricks. The SDK targets (implicitly imported **after** the project by the `SDK="…"` attribute on `<Project/>`) split the `TargetFramework` property into `TargetFrameworkIdentifier` and `TargetFrameworkVersion`.

So `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</…>` will cause:

- `$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)` to be `.NETStandard`
- `$(TargetFrameworkVersion)` to be `v1.5`
- `$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)` to be `1.5`, but this property is "private" per convention (underscore) and shouldn't be used as it is subject to change / not guaranteed to be usable by custom targets.

When comparing strings, MSBuild tries to parse them into versions before comparing so we can compare `'1.5' >= '1.4'`.
Using this, we can hook a target before the compilation process to set custom variables based on version ranges:

```
<Target Name="AddNetStdMinDefine" 
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"
        Condition="('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETStandard' and '$(TargetFrameworkVersion.Substring(1))' &gt;= '1.4')">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);IS_MIN_NETSTANDARD1_4</DefineConstants>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```